# What is the most efficient way to manipulate raw pixels in an SDL2 window in Rust?

Tags: rust, sdl

I would like to efficiently manipulate (on the CPU) the raw pixels that are displayed in an SDL2 window. There is a lot of information on SDL2 out there, but it's mostly for C++ and the relationship to the Rust bindings is not always clear.

I found out that from the window, I can [create a canvas](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.32.2/sdl2/video/struct.Window.html#method.into_canvas), which can [create a](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.32.2/sdl2/render/struct.Canvas.html#method.texture_creator-1) [texture](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.32.2/sdl2/render/struct.TextureCreator.html#method.create_texture_streaming), whose raw data [can be manipulated](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.32.2/sdl2/render/struct.Texture.html#method.with_lock) as expected. That texture must be [copied into the canvas](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.32.2/sdl2/render/struct.Canvas.html#method.copy) to display it.

That works, but it seems like it could be possible to directly access a pixel buffer with the contents of the window and mutate that. Is that the case? That would perhaps be a bit faster and automatically resize with the window. Some other answers led me to believe that a [Surface](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.32.2/sdl2/surface/struct.SurfaceRef.html) already exposes these raw pixels, but

1. These answers always cautioned that using a Surface is inefficient – is that true even for my use case?
2. I could not find out how to get the right Surface. There is Window's [surface](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.32.2/sdl2/video/struct.Window.html#method.surface) method, but if that holds a reference to an EventPump, how can I use the EventPump in the main loop afterwards?

Comment: SDL2 provides two mutually exclusive (i.e. can't be used simultaneously on the same window) methods to draw into window - SDL1.2-style window's `SDL_Surface` and new hardware accelerated `SDL_Renderer`. Directly filling big image with custom pixels would be slow regardless of what method you use. While window surface holds pixels to be displayed, you still need to call `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface`. After resize you'll have to get new window surface as old one may be destroyed by SDL; there are no promises about its contents after resize. I can't help you with anything rust-specific, sorry.